# On Deformation of the body due to dipole orientation in the cells

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, human-anatomy, electrophysiology

Our bodies are made up of billions of atoms and molecules, and each cell has many molecules with dipoles that are initially random and orient themselves in one specific direction when an electric field is applied.

So with the [static fair-weather electric field](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Natural_electric_field_of_the_Earth) in the atmosphere being ~150 volts per meter (V/m) near the Earth's surface,the dipoles in molecules of our body would orient themselves and provide charge to the cell thus changing its geometry, then why isn't all of our bodies deformed?

Comment: 1. "why all of our bodies deformed"? no. what sort of deformation? 2. Are you sure that Earth have an unbalanced electric field at any specific direction? From where you knew this? 3. On application of electric field above a certain limit creates electric current; of course damage take place. We perceive electric shock. Also, strong natural-electric fields like charge in cloud cause thunder. It also works on us and is fatal. So what is new in that?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused sorry that was a typo, I meant "why isn't ". Thanks for pointing that. As for the electric field of earth-The static fair-weather electric field in the atmosphere is ~150 volts per meter (V/m) near the Earth's surface, but it drops exponentially with height to under 1 V/m at 30 km altitude, as the conductivity of the atmosphere increases.

Comment: So far I knew yet ; that earth is neutral. Now you are telling that is wrong and representing an unpopular fact. So please provide verifiable, authentic links in your question. 150 V!  per meter? surprising. in which direction? just like Earth's magnetic field? You may write your question in more straightforward way; that would help reach the question to more people. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen too many advertisements of science museums showing kid touching van-de-graaff-generator  all the hairs spike out; still no death or shock. Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator#/media/File:Maker_Faire_2008_San_Mateo_115_cropped.JPG.  And https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZEFuCxD7BE .surely there is some precausions. but maybe this case is something like that.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused please refer here: https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Natural_electric_field_of_the_Earth.

Comment: It was a polite suggestion to improve your question so that it becomes acceptable to more people. Btw never take criticism by this website from heart. This website is by-its-nature very much critic. But it criticise your statements and ideas; not you.

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please ensure your post is [formatted correctly](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as well